# Google Drive Java API - save file object(s) on device orientation

Tags: android, json, gson, google-drive-api

I'm creating an Android application which uses **Google Drive API/SDK**. How would one save the fetched file/files from Drive if device orientation happens. One option naturally is to re-connect and re-create the objects with the response, but I was wondering if I can use on onSaveInstanceState to achieve this.

---

This is what I'm basically doing;

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

private List<File> mListOfResults = new ArrayList<File>();

Files.List request = mDrive.files().list().setQ(query);
FileList files = request.execute();
mListOfResults.addAll(files.getItems());
```

I noticed that the File class extends `com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson` which probably means that the File is actually an **JSONObject**. 
I can store the object with this:

```
outState.putString(key, mListOfResults.toString();
```

but then re-instanting the object would be a pain in the ass, as I would have to create custom parser for it, as there are multiple class variables.

---

I tried to use **Gson** for this. This is how I tried to accomplish it.

```
String string = new Gson().toJson(files, new TypeToken<FileList>() {}.getType());
outState.putString(RESULT_LIST, string);
```

and

```
FileList fileList = (FileList) new Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString(RESULT_LIST), new TypeToken<FileList>() {}.getType());
mListOfResults.addAll(fileList.getItems());
```

This was the result:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.drive.model.File
```

---

Other attempt with **Gson**;

```
FileList fileList = new FileList();
fileList.setItems(mListOfResults);  
String string = new Gson().toJson(fileList);
outState.putString(RESULT_LIST, string);
```

and

```
FileList fileList = new Gson().fromJson(savedInstanceState.getString(RESULT_LIST), new TypeToken<List<File>>() {}.getType());
```

This was the result:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

---

I also thought that maybe retained fragment could be used, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach. HttpCache, while that would partly solve it, it still would take a bit longer to re-instantiate previous state. Has anyone faced this problem and figured it out? I'm not sure how to proceed and would gladly take advices.

Thank you for your time.